# maven-replacer-plugin to replace tokens in build and not source

Tags: maven, replace, maven-3, maven-war-plugin

I am trying to use the `maven-replacer-plugin` to replace tokens in my `web.xml` when it is built in the WAR file but not in the source, which would remove the tokens for subsequent builds and show the file as changed relative to the version control repository.

Currently, I am only able to change the file in the source, which does not meet my requirement:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</file>
        <replacements>
            <replacement>
                <token>@@sec.level@@</token>
                <value>local</value>
            </replacement>
        </replacements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Question**: How can I run the replacer to only change the file in the WAR package while leaving the source unchanged for subsequent builds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`exploded`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/exploded-mojo.html) goal of the `maven-war-plugin` to get to a temporary folder (like whatever created under `target` actually) the exploded version of what would later on be part of the final `war` file, then execute the `replacer` plugin on this file (a safe copy, not in conflict with other plugins consuming the file).

This approach is actually also documented by the [official replacer plugin doc](https://code.google.com/archive/p/maven-replacer-plugin/wikis/UsageWithOtherPlugins.wiki)

That is, having a similar configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <useCache>true</useCache>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-war</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exploded</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals> 
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/web.xml</file>
        <token>@@sec.level@@</token>
        <value>local</value>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note: the `replacer` documentation also suggests to use the [`useCache`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#useCache) option which should prevent the plugin to override what the `exploded` goal previously created. However, the option doesn't really suit this purpose.

---

Similarly, the following approach would instead work according to my tests:

- Use the `exploded` goal of the `maven-war-plugin` to create a temporary copy of the future war file in a `<war_name>-tmp` directory under `target`: that's not an issue, whatever is under `target` is supposed to be discarded via a `clean` command anyway
- Configure the `replacer` plugin to replace that copy of the `web.xml` file
- Configure the default `war` goal using its [`webXml`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#webXml) option to point to that `web.xml` file for its final `war` file

The following would apply the approach described above:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- explode the future war content for pre-package processing -->
            <id>prepare-war</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exploded</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-tmp</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <!-- use the same execution id to further configure the default binding and execution -->
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- during the package phase, use the processed web.xml file -->
                <webXml>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-tmp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- apply pre-package processing on web resources -->
            <id>process-web-resources</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-tmp/WEB-INF/web.xml</file>
        <token>@@test@@</token>
        <value>local</value>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I already have a plugin declaration for `maven-war-plugin` in my build declaration.  Should i just modify the existing one to add the executions or do I need a whole new declaration ?

Comment: you can add additional executios to the same plugin declaration, also note the global configuration I just added with my latest update

Comment: my `${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/web.xml` does not exist.  my `target` dir contains only `classes`, `generated-sources`, and `test-classes`.  IOW, I can't find the web.xml in the target

Comment: @amphibient I updated my answer with a working (tested) approach, hope it helps